# Convert hex QString to UTF-8 QString

Tags: c++, qt, utf-8

In my project I need to convert a hex QString ("c2a774657374") into a UTF-8 encoded QString ("§test")

My current function (HexToAscii) does convert the hex to ascii, but does not encode it properly:

```
void HexToInt(QString num_hex, int &num_int)
{
    uint num_uint;
    bool ok;
    num_uint = num_hex.toUInt(&ok,16);
    num_int = (int)num_uint;
}

void HexToAscii(QString &Input)//Input == "c2a774657374"
{
    int inputInt;
    QString tempInput;
    for(int i=0; i<Input.length()/2; i++)
    {
        HexToInt(Input.mid(i*2, 2), inputInt);
        tempInput.append((unsigned char)inputInt);
    }
    Input = tempInput;//Input == "Â§test"
}
```

However, this only converts each byte and doesn't follow UTF-8 encoding.
The result of my current function is ("Â§test") when I want it to be ("§test")

How can I edit my HexToAscii function to convert to a UTF-8 encoded QString?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: QString doesn't use UTF-8 encoding interally, so it's unclear what you mean by "a UTF-8 encoded QString".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, on UTF-8, up to 127 it is single byte. The problem is how QString deals with two byte sequences.

The QString cannot tell what "c2" is and proceed to allocate instead to wait for the next byte.

You can fix this by checking if this hex returned is greater than 127 (7f) and concatenating it with the next Hex before appending to QString.

Try:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>


void HexToInt(QString num_hex, int &num_int)
{
    uint num_uint;
    bool ok;
    num_uint = num_hex.toUInt(&ok,16);
    num_int = (int)num_uint;
}

QString HexToAscii(QString Input)//Input == "c2a774657374"
{
    int inputInt;
    int twobytesequece;
    QString tempInput;
    for(int i=0; i<Input.length()/2; i++)
    {
        HexToInt(Input.mid(i*2, 2), inputInt);
        if (inputInt <= 0x7f) {
            tempInput.append((unsigned char)inputInt);
        } else {
            i++;
            HexToInt(Input.mid(i*2, 2), twobytesequece);
            inputInt = inputInt << 8 | twobytesequece;
            tempInput.append((unsigned char)inputInt);
        }
    }
    return tempInput;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QString test = "c2a774657374";
    test = HexToAscii(test);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Just what I needed, let me test this out real quick. :)

Comment: It isn't working, the output seems to still be the hex string for some reason.

Comment: That's really curious. Take a look at my screenshot: [link](https://plus.google.com/100826069654839385250/posts/Dx9eLhp4VKu?pid=6109644456010379762&oid=100826069654839385250)

Comment: Huh, I copied and pasted it directly in place of my current function and all strings that called it seem to return the hex representation. Let me try some things

Comment: I think that i found the problem with your code: instead to pass by reference the QString that calls HextoAscii, return the result back. I will change my response to show to you.

Comment: As you can see: http://gyazo.com/d6519bbf5345e9aa7e850cea5060c5e2 becomes http://gyazo.com/d4298329dc2b9e351fcf9450740b4562 First image is my original code, second is yours.

Comment: Thank you so much. :) That change fixed it. Though I don't really understand why it would be any different. What is different from passing by reference vs returning?

Comment: One other question (even though it's kinda off topic). I have a QLineEdit where the user enters a value which gets converted into the hex representation. The character § (Alt+21) doesn't display when I try entering it. Instead it seems to randomly pick either I or ú. But never §. What makes a QLineEdit different? Any way around to correct that?

Comment: Usually it don't make any difference. But Qt has a tendency to disagree with anything related to pointers. That's due Qt's implicit sharing mechanism: [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html) Take a look here too to have a idea [link](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/8722-Implicit-sharing-vs-c-refereces)

Answer (score 2):

To get a decoded copy of the hex encoded string, you can use [QByteArray::fromHex()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#fromHex) static function.

```
QByteArray hex = QByteArray::fromHex("c2a774657374");
QString str = QString::fromUtf8(hex);
```

Comment: str still ends up being "c2a774657374". I already tried that.

Comment: Hold on, I think I just implemented it wrong. give me a sec.

Comment: What you said also worked, however I had the same problem as CapEnt where simply implementing it into my function wouldn't work. This apparently is because I passed the result by reference instead of returning it. Your answer is also correct (and with much less code) although is was CapEnt that helped me fix my issue so I'm giving him the answer. Both answers are good :)